# \phantom causes a spacing issue between paragraghs

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

Could anybody tell me why does `phantom` command create paragraph spacing issues as described in [this thread](http://typophile.com/node/105707):

> This sort of code
>
> ```
> Vin.\ i zvat.\ mn.\ imaju akcente kao i im.\ mn.: \emph{zȗbe : zȗbi}, 
> \emph{knȅzove : knȅzovi}, \emph{púževe} i t.\ d.
>
> \phantom{a}\symbol{"0311} na ˊ u svima padežima osim onih koji će se 
> na po se spomenuti, n.\ p.\ \emph{strȋc} ima u rod.\ jed.\ \emph{stríca}, dat.: 
> \emph{strícu}, vin.: \emph{stríca}, tvor.: \emph{strícem}, skaz.: \emph{strícu}; 
> tako \emph{dvȏr} ima u im.\ mn.\ \emph{dvóri} i \emph{dvórovi}, i t.\ d.
> ```
>
> produces
>
> [image]
>
> Why the such a big space between the paragraphs?

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 17):

`\phantom` is not a LaTeX documented box command and does not work the same way as `\mbox` etc. You need `\leavevmode\phantom{...}` so the phantom text starts the paragraph.

It's easier to see what is happening if you use `\hbox` rather than `\phantom` so you can see where it is placed. `\hbox` on its own does not start a paragraph, but rather is stacked above the following paragraph, so you see a `b` flush left. The `\phantom` case is the same except you can not see the contents.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}



1 aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 

\hbox{b}bbb bbb bbb

2 aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 

\leavevmode\hbox{b}bbb bbb bbb


3 aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 

\phantom{b}bbb bbb bbb

4 aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 

\leavevmode\phantom{b}bbb bbb bbb

6 aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I presume that the `\hbox` then fills the space from _b_ until the end of that line and then comes the indent and the beginning of the new paragraph; however, why is _b_ before the box?

Comment: @Sylph no the hbox is _just_ around the `b` It comes before the paragraph as TeX is in vertical mode so stacks boxes vertically, you need to start horizontal mode to make things stack horizontally, a letter does that or `\leavevmode` but a box command does not.